# how to insert but get data from multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple SQL insert query, however two of the data entires come from two other tables,

I know how to get data from from one table in an insert but how do i get data from two tables?

Example (One Table Data)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3)
SELECT :COL1, :COL2, TABLE2.ID
FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE2.NAME = :LEVEL0
```

The above works fine and pulls relevant data out of table2, issue is i need to add a third table.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
SELECT :COL1,
       :COL2,
       (TABLE2.ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.NAME = :LEVEL0),
       (TABLE3.ID FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE3.NAME = :LEVEL1)
```

doesn't work i get SQL errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries are *queries*, so they need their own SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
SELECT :COL1,
       :COL2,
       (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE NAME = :LEVEL0),
       (SELECT ID FROM TABLE3 WHERE NAME = :LEVEL1);
```

And when all values are computed by subqueries, you do not need to use the SELECT form of the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
VALUES(:COL1,
       :COL2,
       (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE NAME = :LEVEL0),
       (SELECT ID FROM TABLE3 WHERE NAME = :LEVEL1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally as i asked the question i found the solution 'cross join'

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
SELECT :COL1, :COL2, TABLE2.ID, TABLE3.ID
 FROM TABLE2 CROSS JOIN TABLE3
 WHERE TABLE2.NAME = :LEVEL0 AND TABLE3.NAME = :LEVEL1
```